# Output the tensor product of two matrix as a matrix

Tags: matrix, tensors

[image]
How do I output the matrix form like the RHS without the tensor product sign remaining $\otimes$?

[image]

I need it for display purpose where I can see easily what the form of the whole product matrix is.

Comment: Why can't you post more than two image links? Anyway, you should post code, properly formatted in code blocks, rather than screenshots. Please edit your post and click on the grey question mark on the right-side of the toolbar for help with formatting.  Finally, look up `KroneckerProduct`. `TensorProduct` is for symbolic manipulation, and you seem to want to actually make the matrices: that is implemented as `KroneckerProduct` in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I have under 10 reputations so I cannot post more than two image links.

Comment: @ march I replace `KroneckerProduct` in the command above but it still output does not give me the matrix form with Y inside.

Comment: You literally want it to look like your image, where it's `1*Y` and `0*Y`? That seems weird. Can you explain why you need this? Is it purely for display purposes? Or does it serve some computational purpose? Please edit your post with these details, because depending on which of these it is, the answers you might get will be different.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @march Yes. I need it for display purpose where I can see easily what the form of the whole product matrix is.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say that you still do not get the output you desire using `KroneckerProduct`, I am guessing that you should try restarting the kernel. In any case, this should also fit your needs:

```
mat1 = Array[m1, {2, 2}];
mat2 = Array[m2, {2, 2}];
KroneckerProduct[mat1, mat2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you use `Array` to create elements of matrix? Is `{2,2}` a two by two matrix?

Comment: @diff yes. But of course you can also do it like `{{a,b},{c,d}}`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
 X = IdentityMatrix[2]
 Y = Array[y, {2, 2}]
 TensorProduct[X, Y] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 y(1,1) & y(1,2) \\
 y(2,1) & y(2,2) \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 y(1,1) & y(1,2) \\
 y(2,1) & y(2,2) \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Thanks. But $Y$ here is an array. Is this the same as list, which is a matrix?